# Form validation for all the fields in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I used jQuery Validation Plugin to validate my form i.e. "user-form". When I tried to validate it using valid() method it returns true even if a single input field is filled.

```
if (!$("#user-form").valid()) return false;
```

How do I solve this issue such that it becomes true only after all fields are filled?

Comment: Can you create a code snippet here, it'll helpful to debug then

Comment: try `if($("#user-form").valid()) ? return true : return false;`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/), the `validate()` method needs to be called on the form before you can use `.valid()`.  So, for example:

```
$("#user-form").validate();
if (!$("#user-form").valid()) return false;
```